# How to write a LSTM model with 3 dimensional X_train and Y_trains?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have X_train and Y_train with `[2160,24,3]` dimensions. But when I try a simple LSTM like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(24 , return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(dp))
```

It gives me this error message:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dropout_192 to have
>   shape (24, 24) but got array with shape (24, 3)

And when I try to change my code like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(24 , return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(dp)) 

model.add(RepeatVector(24))
```

I get:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected repeat_vector_55 to
>   have shape (24, 24) but got array with shape (24, 3)

Also:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(24 , return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(dp))   
model.add(RepeatVector(24))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

Or:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(24 , return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(dp))   
model.add(RepeatVector(24))
model.add(LSTM(24 , return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(dp)) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

Gives me:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_56
>   to have shape (24, 1) but got array with shape (24, 3)

I am confused and don't know how to fix it? What I want is train a LSTM model with X_train and Y_train of size `[2160,24,3]`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all the above cases, you are not setting the output shape properly. The last layer should create 3 features.
Try this for example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(24, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(dp)) 
model.add(Dense(3))
```

Comment: Thank you SaTa, it worked, but a new problem arrived! When I try `model.predict(X_test)` that `X_test` has a `[6,24,3]` shape, I get a `[432,1]` shape result, but I expected a shape as same as the `X_test` for my result. So how can I fix it?

Comment: That's odd. Did you get this with the above code? If not, can you post your code?

Comment: Yes, I changed the Dense layer's input to 3, then used that code but got predicted result in a `[432,1]` array instead of  `[6,24,3]`.

Comment: No, sorry. You are right. I was reshaping the result array in some part of my code! Thank you again!